# Do we need to use Virtual keyword while writing properties in my Dto?

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtual, dto

while declaring all properties of my main class I have used Virtual keyword. Now I am wondering if need to use virtual keyword in my dto class or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the conceptual Data Transfer Object is not thought be be a nested class, because it is intended to transfer data.

I sometimes end up with a nested structure where shared values are on the base class(es) but then they are not on the derived classes also.
If imaginable like @tony wrote sure you can - But as the purpose of a DTO is to serialize in and out .net object entities and the wire it is on the verge of being against the concept imho.

Where i would use it is in Model Classes, that which interacts with your business layers and data storage layers, but these I would not use for DTOs to maintain freedom to change things.
So whilst in quick implements DTO classes end up being Model classes too, we should remember that this is a bit hacky and only defendable while the two classes would be identical.

Though with entity framework and the likes, it is not practical to suffix a class with DTO as it is waiting to get stupid-slapped by ones colleagues when the tables are suddently auto generated with the data transfer suffix XD :).

So, No.

Answer (score 1):

Do you foresee other classes inheriting from your DTO's and overriding these properties?

If not, then there's no need to mark them as virtual.

Comment: Nagivation properties might still need to be virtual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4#lazy-loading

Comment: @KlausGütter - Is that the case for a dto? I would presume that it only made sense on entity classes